# send loading status back to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line

I'm building a simple web app that takes a file as input, runs some command-line operations, and then returns a new file (it's an online converter). The whole process takes 1-2 minutes because there are 8 or 9 command-line operations and some take more time than others.

I'm trying to figure out a way to send the status of the conversion to the client in real-time.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
app.post('/convert/', function(req, res) {
   cmd.run(/* operation 1 */);
   cmd.run(/* operation 2 */);
   ...
   cmd.run(/* operation 7 */);
   cmd.run(/* operation 8 */);
   cmd.run(/* operation 9 */);
});
```

I would like to know if there is a way to send something back to the client when one command-line command has finished executing without any refresh needed. **The final goal is to have a clean loading bar.** I know the solution probably lies in Ajax, but at this point I'm too much of a beginner to know what I should do.

I tried stuff like

```
res.write('step 1 done');
```

and

```
res.send('step 1 done');
```

but it stops executing the rest of the script and loads another page in the browser. I would also like to know how I can handle this response in the client's browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to send **multiple** responses to a **single** request. Unfortunatelly [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) by itself doesn't work quite like that. you'll not be able to achieve this by using HTTP as you're currently doing.

A viable approach would be to create an [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) between your client and your server. The WebSocket is a protocol created upon the HTTP protocol and as stated

> WebSockets is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

I'd recommend reading the Mozilla Developer Network tutorials on this, or to use [socket.io](https://socket.io/). [Here's](http://www.programwitherik.com/getting-started-with-socket-io-node-js-and-express/) a tutorial of how to create a Node application with express and socketIO

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that one advantage of Node over, let's say PHP or Python was that it was easy to send and receive data from the server to the browser without refresh... apparently it's  not